# Exception breakpoint hits the titleTextAttributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, xcode7.3

When the exception breakpoint is turned on, the following line gets hit everytime I run my project:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold" size:20.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor secondaryAppColor]};
```

It doesn't crash but it gets stopped at this line. I had to hit continue execution to move on. I'm calling this in `viewDidLoad`.

Edit: I removed all breakpoints, and left only the exception breakpoint. Still the xcode stops at the same line.

[image]

Why is it happening ?

Comment: Hit Cmd+7 in Xcode, and see if there is a breakpoint set somewhere. You can delete them just by selecting and hitting the delete key

Comment: Delete all breakpoints and clean. Otherwise debug and look at the stack trace in that moment, you can see if a particular thread is doing something strange.

Comment: Do you want me to add exception breakpoint after deleting all breakpoints ?@simpleBob@lublis

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Does your `breakpoint navigator` (View/Navigators/Show Breakpoint Navigator, just in case you have a different key combo) show "No Breakpoints"?

Comment: I hve only one breakpoint which is exception breakpoint. If I remove that too, execution will not stop at that line.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri are you sure that the color exists?

Comment: You could try changing your breakpoint from All to Objective-C.

Comment: when your breakpoint hits, check all your values in the debug console, probably something is `nil`. Maybe the font can't be found?

Comment: Changing it to Objective-c from All worked. @JamesP

Comment: Does anyone have an actual solution to this problem other than ignoring that the problem exists?